# networking the internet

Tags: networking

on my desk top i have modem connected to my computer for a wired connection 
i am thinking of buying a wirless linksys router to connect to my modem 
i just bought another desktop and i want to use a wireless usb can that be done

Answer (score 1):

You could. Generally modem (with ethernet) -> router -> computer will work.

Personally i find that internal PCI cards are easier for desktops than USB keys, but there's no reason a USB wireless dongle will not work

Answer (score 0):

That works but I'd prefer to put a cable if possible... I used 4 different types wireless cards(2) and USB(2) for 2 years and now the 4 pcs are connected with a cable as the performance was terrible, even with good signal and dropping connection a lot (one computer alone was ok). On the same router, I can connect many wireless notebooks very well so the problem was with the wireless adaptors on the desktops and not with the router.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a USB dongle for wireless on a desktop. I'm doing it right now. USB dongles can sometimes overheat, so I would recommend placing it in the USB port that is closest to the system fan on the case.

The other option is a PCI card. This has the disadvantage that you need to open the case up. However, they are often cheaper.